# Replacing the image within an image src tag

Tags: php

I have the following situation, I have an html file with image tags about 10 or more, but it varies. Now what I want to achieve is to replace the image src with a PHP function as example below

I want to replace something like this

```
<img src="image1.png" .... 
<img src="image2.png" ....
```

with this

```
<img src="<?=imageResize('image1.png',20,15)?>" ...
<img src="<?=imageResize('image2.png',20,15)?>" ..`.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: will the img tag always be written `<img src=""`?

Comment: @Gordon - Yes, it will always start with <img src="" but other attributes after the img will varie

Comment: Do you want to manipulate HTML? If this is the case, you are going to need a DOM-parser.

Comment: @elusive - Yes I want to manipulate the HTML

Comment: @elusive: not really, regular expression will be fine ;)

Comment: At the moment I don t care how it is done, it should just work, since I have a due date that I need to reach on this

Comment: @Roland: Take a look at PHP's [DOM](http://php.net/dom). @rhino: You _can_ do it using regular expressions, but you shouldn't.

Comment: @elusive, will def have a look at it

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: @Roland no problem. If the markup is really always the same format for the to be replaced parts, Regex is the easiest approach. Actually, I am not even sure you can put a processing instruction as a DOMAttr value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that the current page source is contained in `$source`. Try some regular expressions:

```
<?php
preg_replace ('/<img src="(.+)"/Ui', '<img src="<?=imageResize(\'\\1\',20,15)?>"', $source);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 cases:

- Your imageResize function resizes the image, creating a new one with a different name (something like image120x15.png) and returning a string with the image name. In this case you should do something like:

> ```
> <img src="<?php echo imageResize('image1.png',20,15);?>" ...
> ```

- Your imageResize actually resizes the initial image and overriding it. In this case, do something like:

> ```
> <?php imageResize('image1.png',20,15);?>
> <img src="image1.png" ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Capture output with output buffer and then apply regex for replace.

```
<?ob_strart();?>
<img src="image1.png" /> 
<img src="image2.png" />

<?php
$cnt = ob_get_clean();
$cnt = preg_replace ('/<img src="([^"]+)"/', '<img src="<?=imageResize(\'\\1\',20,15)?>"', $cnt);?>
```

For execute function imageresize you must run output in eval().